# plotly can't seem to create my interactive plot in pycharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pycharm, plotly

I'm trying to use plotly and cufflinks for python in pycharm. I use iplot but it's just not working.
Does anyone knows why?

Thanks in advance!

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, plot, iplot
import cufflinks as cf


df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 4), columns=['a','b','c','d'])

df2=pd.DataFrame({'cate':['a', 'b', 'c'],'values':[53, 67, 22]})

df.iplot()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `fig.show()`:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import cufflinks as cf

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 4), columns=['a','b','c','d'])

fig = df.iplot(asFigure =True,
               xTitle = "The X Axis",
               yTitle = "The Y Axis",
               title = "The Figure Title")
fig.show()
```

and you get:

[image]